# Why won't pygame display my images or chessboard?

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm, python-3.7

I'm using Pycharm Community 2020 for my IDE. I'm using Python 3.7.4. I have the Pygame 1.9.6.
So I've been following a YouTube video on how to code a working chessboard, but it isn't display my board to me with the pieces on it or anything.

I have to separate python files to do this one for the ***Chess engine*** which is responsible for storing all the information about the current state of a chess game. Also will be responsible for determining the valid moves at the current state. It will also keep move log. Another is ***Chess Main*** which is the main driver file. It's responsible for handling user input and displaying the current game state object.
Chess main code:

```py
WIDTH = HEIGHT = 512  # 400 is another option
DIMENSION = 8  # dimensions of a chess board are 8x8
SQ_SIZE = HEIGHT // DIMENSION
MAX_FPS = 15  # for animations later on
IMAGES = {}

def loadImages():
    pieces = ['wp', 'wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wK', 'wQ', 'bp', 'bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bK', 'bQ']
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[piece] = p.transform.scale(p.image.load("images/" + piece + ".png"), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
        
# Note: we can access an image saving "IMAGES"['wp']
def main():
    p.init()
    screen = p.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    clock = p.time.Clock()
    screen.fill(p.Color("white"))
    gs = ChessEngine.GameState()
    loadImages()  # only do this once, before the while loop
    running = True
    sqSelected = ()  # no square is selected, keep track of the last click of the user (tuple: (row, col))
    player_Clicks = []  # keep track of player clicks (two tuples [6,4), (4,4)]
    while running:
        for e in p.event.get():
            if e.type == p.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif e.type == p.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                location = p.mouse.get_pos()  # (x, y) location of mouse
                col = location[0]//SQ_SIZE
                row = location[1]//SQ_SIZE
                if sqSelected == (row, col):  # the user clicked the same square twice
                    sqSelected = ()  # deselect
                    player_Clicks = []  # clear player clicks
                else:
                    sqSelected = (row, col)
                    player_Clicks.append(sqSelected)  # append for both 1st and 2nd clicks
                if len(player_Clicks) == 2:  # after 2nd click
                    move = ChessEngine.Move(player_Clicks[0], player_Clicks[1], gs.board)
                    print(move.getChessNotation())
                    gs.makeMove(move)
                    sqSelected = ()  # reset user clicks
                    player_Clicks = []

        drawGameState(screen, gs)
        clock.tick(MAX_FPS)
        p.display.flip()


def drawGameState(screen, gs):
    drawBoard(screen)  # draw squares on the board
    # add in piece highlighting or move suggestions (later)
    drawPieces(screen, gs.board)  # draw pieces on top of those squares

def drawBoard(screen):
    colors = [p.Color("white"), p.Color("gray")]
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            color = colors[((r+c) % 2)]
            p.draw.rect(screen, color, p.Rect(c * SQ_SIZE, r * SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))

    def drawPieces(screen, board):
        for r in range(DIMENSION):
            for c in range(DIMENSION):
                piece = board[r][c]
                if piece != "--":  # not empty square
                    screen.blit(IMAGES)[piece], p.Rect(c * SQ_SIZE, r * SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE)

if __name__ == " __main__":
    main()
```

Chess engine code:

```py
class GameState:
    def __init__(self):
        # board is an 8x8 2d list, each element of lest has 2 character.
        # The first character represents the color of the piece, "b" or "w"
        # The second character represents the type of the piece, "K", "Q", "R", "B", "N", or "p"
        # "--" - represents an empty space with no piece.
        self.board = [
            ["bR", "bN", "bB", "bQ", "bK", "b8", "bN", "bR"],
            ["bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp"],
            ["wR", "wN", "wB", "wQ", "wK", "w8", "wN", "wR"]]
        self.whiteToMove = True
        self.moveLog = []

    def makeMove(self, move):
        self.board[move.startRow][move.startCol] = "--"
        self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol] = move.pieceMoved
        self.moveLog.append(move)  # log the move so we can undo it later
        self.whiteToMove = not self.whiteToMove  # swap players


class Move():
    # maps key to values
    # key : value
    ranksToRows = {"1": 7, "2": 6, "3": 5, "4": 4,
                "5": 3, "6": 2, "7": 1, "8": 0}
    rowsToRanks = {v: k for k, v in ranksToRows.items()}
    filesToCols = {"a": 0, "b": 1, "c": 2, "d": 3,
                "e": 4, "f": 5, "g": 6, "h": 7}
    colsToFiles = {v: k for k, v in filesToCols.items()}

    def __init__(self, startSq, endSq, board):
        self.startRow = startSq[0]
        self.startCol = startSq[1]
        self.endRow = endSq[0]
        self.endCol = endSq[1]
        self.pieceMoved = board[self.startRow][self.startCol]
        self.pieceCaptured = board[self.endRow][self.endCol]

    def getChessNotation(self):
        # you can add to make this like real chess notation
        return self.getRankFile(self.startRow, self.startCol) * self.getRankFile(self.endRow, self.endCol)

    def getRankFile(self, r, c):
        return self.colsToFiles[c] * self.rowsToRanks[r]
```

So I don't know why Pycharm isn't displaying the board if you want the YouTube links for the first 2 videos I've seen of this:
Part 1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnYui0e73Rs

Part 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o24J3WcBGLg

Edit: I fixed the issues from the first answer and got it to work. Plus had to fix the if **name** == "**main**": (main). To just (main). Now it doesn't want to move the pieces properly or register the mouse clicks. I am now going threw the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 105, in <module>
   main()
  line 58, in main
    print(move.getChessNotation())
   line 52, in getChessNotation
    return self.getRankFile(self.startRow, self.startCol) * 
 self.getRankFile(self.endRow, self.endCol)
  line 55, in getRankFile
    return self.colsToFiles[c] * self.rowsToRanks[r]
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the statement which blits the images is semantically wrong:

<s>`creen.blit(IMAGES)[piece], p.Rect(c * SQ_SIZE, r * SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE)`</s>

```py
screen.blit(IMAGES[piece], p.Rect(c * SQ_SIZE, r * SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
```

Furthermore, the figures "b8" and ""w8" doesn't exist. You probably meant "bB" and "wB". Fix the figure names is attribute `self.board` in the class `GameState`.